# Token passport Laravel not updating when this. $ Router.push only window.location.href

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, laravel-passport

I am using passport from Laravel and Vue in the front-end, but when I am passing the token as a header in the requests when doing

> this.$router.push ({name: "store-list"})

; the page is not updated with the new token ... you have to refresh the page or use

> window.location.href

so that it appears with the new one and its content. Can you do something or just use window.location.href?

Comment: Watch the router change and when it does, enact an XHR request to refresh the token

Comment: You mean in router.beforeEach? Excuse me, I'm a newbie, thanks for your time.